# Changing the data in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have an array called char a[5][5]

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~

I wanted a char ball = 'b' to go through the array like this:

b ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
b ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
b ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
b ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
b ~ ~ ~ ~

It does not have to be specifically for that first column. 
How would I approach this?

Comment: Alternative: store an `x` and a `y` coordinate and use that to move your character (if it's just one). Otherwise, just use indices `arr[0][1] = arr[0][0]; arr[0][0] = '~'`

Comment: A "dptr"? If you mean a "double pointer" then no, beause an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.

Comment: Store the `row` and `col`umn of the ball and move it downwards (`arr[--row][col] = 'b'; arr[row + 1][col] = '~';`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 char a[5][5];
 char ball = 'b';

 for (int iter = 0; iter <5; iter++)
 {
     for (int i= 0; i<5; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
         {
             if( (j == 0) && (iter == i) ) //First element of a row
                 a[i][j] = ball;
             else
                 a[i][j] = '~';
             printf("%c ",a[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array[x][y], going through it with any cycle with the length of x if you're changing values in a single row, or y if changing values of a column.

Example:

```
for(int x=0;x<lengthOfMatrixColumn;x++) {
    array[0][x]=B //character you're using
}
```